# Calculate Time Difference between events in streaming datasets

Tags: apache-spark, distributed-computing, flink-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

In my application, events are generated for every action that user performs, and events are generated with data in the below format -

> user_id | step_num | event_timestamp

Order in which these events are streamed are not completely strict i.e. we might have user 2 data streamed in before all events of user 1 are captured.

Sample Data

u1, 1, 2020-05-30 00:00:01

u1, 2, 2020-05-30 00:00:02

u2, 1, 2020-05-30 00:00:02

u3, 1, 2020-05-30 00:00:02

u1, 3, 2020-05-30 00:00:03

....

How would you implement any streaming solution to calculate average time taken for each step. We can assume total time taken by a user for each step to be (time_stamp_at_step_1 - time_stamp_at_step_0).

I am using Spark Streaming to build the solution but could not find anything to compute statistics taking data from 2 event that are grouped by an attribute(user_id in my case). Would love to know if there are any available solutions in other streaming tech like Flink, Kafka etc.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done in various ways with Flink, but one approach would be to use Flink SQL with MATCH_RECOGNIZE:

```
SELECT step_num, AVG(seconds)
FROM events
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
    PARTITION BY userId
    ORDER BY eventTime
    MEASURES
        this_step.userId as id
        this_step.step AS step_num
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, this_step.eventTime, next_step.eventTime) AS seconds
    AFTER MATCH SKIP TO LAST next_step
    PATTERN (this_step next_step)
    DEFINE
        this_step AS TRUE,
        next_step AS next_step.step = this_step.step + 1
)
GROUP BY step_num
```

Comment: Can I use window() to group the events over a time range and calculate the average times. For eg, for a pre-defined 5-min window of 12:00 - 12:05, avg times for each step. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can also group by time windows.

Comment: TIme windows for SQL are documented at https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/sql/queries.html#group-windows and there are examples in the SQL training at https://github.com/ververica/sql-training/wiki/Querying-Dynamic-Tables-with-SQL.